# Vertical alignment of html boxes

Tags: php, html, css

I am displaying US state names via php loop which are basically my posts. These are fully responsive but client wants state names in vertical alignment.
Here is how these are displaying right now
[image]

My client want these in this way
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No i am not using bootstrap.

Comment: it's me or there is no difference in both screenshot ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No there is a difference, notice that on the right of **Alabama** in the 1st pic It's **Alaska** and in 2nd one It's **Hawaii**

Comment: No these are different and you can see in first screen shot state names are in horizontal alignment and in second screen shot state names are in vertical alignment.

Comment: What's your current PHP code?  How have you tried to modify the code to meet your new goals, and what problems did you run into in the attempt?  See:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MehdiBounya i notice this :) and it's not a difference for me ... as you can simply switch content .. since there is no code provided and you only provided a screenshot, so no issue ;) simply switch items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try columns property of unordered list.

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Alabama</li>
  <li>Alaska</li>
  <li>Arizona</li>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Texas</li>
  <li>Virginia</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I really appreciate all answers but for me this one is working. I will just have to use some media query to reduce columns for mobile view. Thank you @izulito for your help.

Comment: No problem at all. I know there are better and more time consuming ways to that. However, this one is fast and easy.

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is to make use of **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. What you want to do is set a `height` for both the container and the items, and then make use of **[`flex-direction: column`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)** to order vertically. **[`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/)** ensures that once there are more items than the container can handle, the items overflow to the next column.

On top of this, you can use a combination of **[`align-items: center`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)** and **[`justify-content: center`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)** to ensure that all items are centered both horizontally and vertically.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

This way, you simply have to output your states in a straightforward loop such as:

```
echo "<div class='item'>" . $state . "</div>";
```

Without worrying about any 'fancy' PHP work.

Hope this helps! :)